# sony add-on sdk 2.0?

Tags: android, sdk, sony, sony-smartwatch

I would like to make an app for my Sony Smartwatch SW2.
As I have an Android 4.1.2 (API 16) phone (it does not support higher versions), I guess I must use Sony Add-on SDK 2.0.

But I am having a hard times finding this 2.0 version, as the older developer pages, although writing exactly about 2.0 version, give the link to the official pages where one can find the only the latest SDK v3.0.

But with SDK v3.0 the minimum supported Android is API 19.

Where can I find Sony Add-on SDK 2.0? Or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 0):

You can download v3.0, all what you'll need for SW2 is the samples that can be founded on Android-sdk/add-ons/addon-sony_add-on_sdk_3_0-sony-19/samples/SmartExtensions/

Answer (score 0):

Initially I installed "Sony Add-on SDK 3.0", but in Android Studio it has been installed under "Android 4.4.2 (API 19)".

My main concern is will the app work on SW2 + an old smartphone with "Android 4.1.2 (API 16)" - (no upgrade possible) - I guess not?

The very reason I bought SW2 instead of SW3 is that SW2 supports older Androids starting with 4.0, so I can use it with my Galaxy S2.